# Pandas csv write not understanding empty space inside double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm currently trying to read a csv file, add/delete/rename some columns using Pandas dataframe, and then write it back to the same file. However, a few of the files I'm using contain records which look like this:

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4
123," ",ABCD,"This, that, and this"
```

I was able to successfully get Pandas to understand "This, that, and this" and write it back to the csv exactly the same with the quotation marks and commas. But unfortunately I can't seem to get the empty space surrounded by quotations " ". It will just write it back like this:

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4
123, ,ABC,"This, that, and this"
```

My read looks like:

```
f = pd.read_csv((mypath + file), skipinitialspace=True, quotechar='"')
```

And my write looks like:

```
f.to_csv((mypath + file), index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still a valid CSV without the quotes around the space. A field only needs to be quoted if it contains the separator (comma).

You don't need `skipinitalspace=True` on the read. That's only needed if the CSV looks like `A, B, C, D` instead of `A,B,C,D`.

The `quotechar` parameter isn't needed either as `"` is the default.

The best you can do with `pandas` is quote everything if you need it:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

f = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
f.to_csv('out.csv',index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Given: sample.csv

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4
123," ",ABCD,"This, that, and this"
```

Result: out.csv

```
"Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4"
"123"," ","ABCD","This, that, and this"
```

Comment: @ArrogantCoder The original file is valid, and the new file is valid.  Both will read in as Column 2 has a single space in that column.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately I have to keep all the values from the original file the same, so I cannot add more quotation marks. This is because the file is being fed into another program whose logic I can't change

Comment: @ArrogantCoder Is something else reading the file that actually cares?  The quotes are there only to make sure columns with commas in the data aren't confused with column separators.  Pandas certainly won't care if quotes are added or removed, except for the column that actually has commas in the field.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the other program needs the original formatting unfortunately

Comment: @ArrogantCoder I don't think you can achieve what you want with `pandas` or the built-in `csv` module.  You'd have to roll your own solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help, if I can find a solution I will post it here

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you can use quoting in to_csv to quote all strings

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_csv(('test.csv'), skipinitialspace=True, quotechar='"')
f.to_csv(('test2.csv'), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, index=False)
```

and the output like this

```
"Column 1","Column 2","Column 3","Column 4"
123," ","ABCD","This, that, and this"
```

or you can replace blank space with '" "' but the output will contain triple quote like """"""

```py
f = pd.read_csv(('test.csv'), skipinitialspace=True, quotechar='"')
f["Column 2"] = f["Column 2"].replace(r'^\s*$', '\" \"', regex=True)
f.to_csv(('test2.csv'), index=False)
```

and the output like this

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4
123,""" """,ABCD,"This, that, and this"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. For anyone who might stumble on this post, I used your suggestion and then cleaned up the triple quotes by using this sed command `sed -i 's/""" """/" "/ig' *.csv`